# function missing on window object

Tags: javascript

in the following code console.log(this) in the street function prints "window" object. I understand why it does but then I expected the property street on the window object ( as it was the caller of street function ) . That is not the case, can someone pls explain where this property lives?

```
***
const person ={
  name :"peter",
  Address: function(){    
    let number = "8D"    
    const street = function (){
      console.log("Street")
      console.log(this)      
    }
    street()     
  }    
}  

console.log(person.Address())
***
```

Comment: here is the codepen https://codepen.io/punjabimundaaa/pen/GRNYQjO

Comment: `street` is not a property of any object, it's a local variable in `person.Address` method.

Comment: You very have very fundamental misconceptions about closures and `this`, seemingly mixing up aspects of the two.

Comment: Have a look at Kylie Simsons book on Scope and Closure; readble on github: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed/scope%20%26%20closures

Answer (score 0):

Just because the function is declared inside it doesn't mean it'll share the same context. JavaScript contexts are weird.

You should store a reference to it if it must be in another function, or just put those lines outside.

```js
const person ={
  name :"peter",
  Address: function(){    
    let number = "8D"   
    let thisPerson = this;
    const street = function (){
      console.log("Street")
      console.log(thisPerson)      
    }
    street()     
  }    
}
```

```js
const person ={
  name :"peter",
  Address: function(){    
    let number = "8D"    
    console.log("Street")
    console.log(this)      
    street()     
  }    
}
```

Comment: thanks. I understand that the this is referring to window and not person. My question is, when i  console log the window object  it does not show the proprty  "street".  I expected it to be there